# Как правильно заполнить map с перемещением памяти

Tags: c++, vector, map, directx

Имеется следующие структуры:

```
typedef struct dxgi_adapter_output
{
    IDXGIOutput                                         *p_output;
    DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC                                    m_output_desc;
    std::map<DXGI_FORMAT, std::vector<DXGI_MODE_DESC>>  m_modes;

} dxgi_adapter_output_t;

typedef struct dxgi_adapter
{
    IDXGIAdapter1                       *p_adapter;
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1                  m_adapter_desc;
    std::vector<dxgi_adapter_output>    m_outputs;
} dxgi_adapter_t;
```

А так же класс, который заправляет всем этим делом:

> dxgi_helper.h

```
class dxgi_helper
{
private:
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGIFactory1>   m_factory_;
    std::vector<dxgi_adapter>               m_adapters_;

public:
    dxgi_helper();
    ~dxgi_helper();
};
```

> dxgi_helper.cpp

```
#pragma region Macro goes here

#define THROW_ON_FAIL(RESULT, MESSAGE) \
if(FAILED((HRESULT)(RESULT))) \
{ \
    throw std::runtime_error(MESSAGE); \
}

#define PRINT_MSGW(MESSAGE) printf("[ %p (%s) ] Warning: %ls\n", this, __func__,  (MESSAGE))
#define PRINT_MSG(MESSAGE) printf("[ %p (%s) ] Message: %ls\n", this, __func__, (MESSAGE))
#define PRINT_MSGE(MESSAGE) printf("[ %p (%s) ] Error: %ls\n", this, __func__, (MESSAGE))
#define PRINT_FUNC PRINT_MSG(__func__)

#pragma endregion


dxgi_helper::dxgi_helper()
{
    PRINT_FUNC;

    HRESULT result = CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_PPV_ARGS(m_factory_.GetAddressOf()));

    THROW_ON_FAIL(result, "Failed to init IDXGIFactory");

    uint32_t adapters_length = 0;

    IDXGIAdapter1 *c_adapter = NULL;

    while (m_factory_->EnumAdapters1(adapters_length, &c_adapter) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        dxgi_adapter_t adapter;
        HRESULT result = c_adapter->GetDesc1(&adapter.m_adapter_desc);

        if (result != S_OK)
        {
            PRINT_MSGW("Failed to get adapter description!");
            std::memset(&adapter.m_adapter_desc, 0, sizeof(adapter.m_adapter_desc));
        }

        adapter.p_adapter = c_adapter;

        uint32_t outputs_count = 0;

        IDXGIOutput *c_output = NULL;

        while (c_adapter->EnumOutputs(outputs_count, &c_output) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            dxgi_adapter_output_t adapter_output;

            if (c_output->GetDesc(&adapter_output.m_output_desc) != S_OK)
            {
                PRINT_MSGW("Unable to get description about outputs with adapter.");
                std::memset(&adapter_output.m_output_desc, 0, sizeof(adapter_output.m_output_desc));
            }

            for (int i = DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_FORCE_UINT; i < DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_BC7_UNORM_SRGB; i++)
            {
                uint32_t modes_count = 0;
                c_output->GetDisplayModeList((DXGI_FORMAT)i, DXGI_ENUM_MODES_INTERLACED, &modes_count, NULL);
                DXGI_MODE_DESC* arr_descs = new DXGI_MODE_DESC[modes_count];
                std::vector<DXGI_MODE_DESC> modes(modes_count);
                for (size_t i = 0; i < modes_count; i++)
                {
                    modes.push_back(arr_descs[i]);
                }
                delete[] arr_descs;
                adapter_output.m_modes.insert(std::make_pair((DXGI_FORMAT)i, std::move(modes))); // Здесь кладется мусор вместо перемещенного `vector`
            }

            adapter_output.p_output = c_output;

            adapter.m_outputs.push_back(adapter_output);
            ++outputs_count;
        }

        m_adapters_.push_back(adapter);

        ++adapters_length;

        c_adapter = NULL;
    }
}

dxgi_helper::~dxgi_helper()
{
    PRINT_FUNC;

    for (const dxgi_adapter_t& adapter : m_adapters_)
    {
        PRINT_MSG(adapter.m_adapter_desc.Description);

        for (const dxgi_adapter_output& output : adapter.m_outputs)
        {
            output.p_output->Release();
        }

        adapter.p_adapter->Release();
    }
    m_adapters_.clear();
}
```

В конечном итоге, вектор в `map` `dxgi_adapter_output.m_modes.second` всегда содержит мусор.

Как правильно копировать/переместить вектор дабы в нем были нормальные данные а не мусор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, вы наполняете свой вектор значениями `arr_descs[i]`, которые в этот момент еще *даже не инициализированы*. Вот это и есть мусор. Вы его сами в свой вектор напихали. К перемещению это пока никакого отношения не имеет вообще.

Во-вторых, выглядит как типичная ошибка с перепутанным size и capacity

```
            std::vector<DXGI_MODE_DESC> modes(modes_count);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < modes_count; i++)
            {
                modes.push_back(arr_descs[i]);
            }
```

Создается вектор размера `modes_count` с нулевыми данными внутри. Затем уже *за* этими нулевыми данными в вектор при помощи `push_back` добавляют еще `modes_count` элементов. Получается вектор с `2 * modes_count` элементами, первая половина которых - нулевые, а вторая половина которых содержит мусор из `arr_descs[]`.

Именно этот вектор вы потом и перемещаете. Весь мусор в нем вы сами и создали, еще до перемещения.

Вам именно это надо было получить? Подозреваю, что нет. Подозреваю, что вам нужно было либо

```
            std::vector<DXGI_MODE_DESC> modes;
            modes.reserve(modes_count);

            for (size_t i = 0; i < modes_count; i++)
            {
                modes.push_back(arr_descs[i]);
            }
```

Либо

```
            std::vector<DXGI_MODE_DESC> modes(modes_count);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < modes_count; i++)
            {
                modes[i] = arr_descs[i];
            }
```

Последнее, вообще-то, можно записать как

```
            std::vector<DXGI_MODE_DESC> modes(arr_descs, arr_descs + modes_count);
```

Хотя, еще раз, мне совершенно не ясно, почему у вас к этому моменту используется неинициализированный `arr_descs[i]`. Более того, совершенно не ясно, зачем вообще понадобился массив `arr_descs[]`.

Comment: Проглядел, не сделал второй вызов `GetDisplayModeList`, хотел бы еще узнать могу ли я передать как-то вектор с `GetDisplayModeList`, что бы заполнить его а не массив временный массив?

Comment: @LLENN: Пожалуйста. Сначала задайте вектору требуемый размер `std::vector<DXGI_MODE_DESC> modes(modes_count);`, после чего смело передавайте в `GetDisplayModeList` указатель `&modes[0]` (или `&modes.front()`, что то же самое). Данные заполнятся сразу в вектор. Никакого промежуточного `arr_descs` не надо.